# FreePascal: Free pointer to class

Tags: pointers, double, freepascal

I'm writing a DLL to interface with Game Maker. (Game maker only deals in `Double`s.)

Here's a function:

```
function CreateBitmap(W, H: Double): Double;
var
  TBM: TBitmap;
begin
  TBM := TBitmap.Create(Floor(W), Floor(H));
  CreateBitmap := Double(Integer(@TBM));
end;
```

So when I get the Double back:

```
function DestroyBitmap(Handle: Double);
begin
  <How do I free it?>
end;
```

How do I free this Double? I tried doing

```
function DestroyBitmap(Handle: Double);
var
  Blittable: IBlittable;
begin
  Blittable := Pointer(Floor(Handle))^
  Blittable.Free;
end;
```

But since the pointer's type cannot be determined, the `Blittable` (`IBlittable`) cannot be set to `"untyped"`.

How do I free this pointer without leaking memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@` - that gets the address of the local variable:

```
function CreateBitmap(W, H: Double): Double;
var
  TBM: TBitmap;
begin
  TBM := TBitmap.Create(Floor(W), Floor(H));
  CreateBitmap := Double(Integer(TBM));
end;

function DestroyBitmap(Handle: Double);
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap(integer(Handle));
  bmp.Free;
end;
```